# Why am I getting NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to follow the procedure at https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html but am getting

> Err:6
> http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu
> focal InRelease
> The following signatures couldn't be
> verified because the public key is not
> available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654

Why is this happening and is there a way I can fix it? I am running Ubuntu MATE' 20.04 on my laptop.

8-Dale

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411419/why-am-i-getting--no_pubkey-f42ed6fbab17c654??/) by [hybotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/134211/hybotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you set up your sources?

https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html#setup-sources

Especially, the ROS 2 GPG key with apt and the repository added to your sources list.

Debian packages for ROS 2 Humble Hawksbill are currently available for Ubuntu Jammy (Ubuntu 22.04). You are running Ubuntu MATE 20.04. Maybe this is the problem here?

You can build it from source (check code tab with "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"):

- https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html#system-requirements
- https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html#install-development-tools-and-ros-tools

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2023-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0